# A problem of collinearity - is it appropriate to use barycentric coordinates?

Tags: geometry, barycentric-coordinates

Triangle $ABC$ is inscribed in circle $\omega$. Point $P$ lies on line $BC$ such that line $\overline{PA}$ is tangent to $\omega$. The bisector of $\angle APB$ meets segments $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{AC}$ at $D$ and $E$ respectively. Segments $\overline{BE}$ and $\overline{CD}$ meet at $Q$. Given that line $\overline{PQ}$ passes through the center of $\omega$, compute $\angle BAC$.

[image]

I tried drawing a diagram, but this led to many problems. I thought of using trigonometry, which seemed like a good idea at first, but then crashed and failed. People are recommending a topic called barycentric coordinates. Can someone guide me through the solution and then point me towards a credible source? Thank you!

Comment: Once an origin is fixed, any point $P$ of the plane can be written as $\alpha A+\beta B+\gamma C$ with $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=1$. The triple $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ gives the exact [barycentric coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system) of $P$. [These notes](http://web.evanchen.cc/handouts/bary/bary-short.pdf) by Evan Chen can be used to learn managing them.

Comment: Given some line $\ell$ through $P$, by defining $D_\ell$ and $E_\ell$ as the intersections of $\ell$ with $AB$ and $AC$, we have that $CD_\ell\cap BE_\ell$ lies on the [polar](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polar.html) line of $P$ with respect to $\omega$, which is orthogonal to $OP$. So if $Q$ lies on $OP$ we have that $P$ and $Q$ are mapped into each other by a circle inversion with respect to $\omega$, and $OP\cdot OQ=R^2$. We have $PA^2=PB\cdot PC$ and by the bisector theorem it follows that $AD=AE$. You should have enough elements for completing an elementary solution.

Answer (score 1):

Produce BO to cut the circle at X. Join CX. From A, drop the perpendicular to PE cutting the circle at Y. Join YB, YO, YX and YC.

[image]

After making the necessary constructions, we have all same color coded angles are equal. In particular, $\phi = 0.5 \theta$; and $\angle BCX = 90^0$ ….. (0).

$\phi_2 = \phi_3$ implies $OY // XC$. …. (1)

Let OY cut BC at Z. Because OBYC is a kite, $\angle OZC = 90^0$ ..... (2)

Let T be the midpoint of XC (i.e. XT = TC). Then $\angle OTC = 90^0$ ….. (3)

All of the above make sure that OZTX is a //gm; and OZCT is a rectangle. Therefore, OYCX is rhombus. This makes the already isosceles $\triangle XOC$ equilateral. Hence $\theta = 60^0$.